# How can I add a list of items in a popover by using sap ui5?

Tags: json, list, popover, sapui5

I'm trying to add a list of items in a popover but somehow is not working :/
I populate the list with data from a JSON file. Please find below my code:

```
var popoverButton = new sap.ui.unified.ShellHeadItem("popoverButton",{
         tooltip: "Configuration",
         icon: "sap-icon://generate-shortcut",
         showSeparator:false,
         press:function(oEvent){

                   var oButton = oEvent.getSource();

                    if (!this._oPopover){
                        this._oPopover = new sap.m.Popover("popover",{
                            id:"pop",
                            placement:sap.m.PlacementType.Bottom,
                            showHeader:false,
                            contentWidth:"320px",
                            contentHight:"500px"

                            });

                 }

                    this._oPopover.openBy(oButton);


            this._oPopover.addContent(oList);
                    return ("pop");    
                }

        }); 


    var oTemplate = new sap.m.StandardListItem({
        title : "{title}",  
        icon:"{icon}",
        description: "{description}",
        type : sap.m.ListType.Active});

    var oList = new sap.m.List({ 
        items : {path:"/Menu", template:oTemplate}


            });
```

And this is how I load the JSON file in the controller:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("model/menu.json");
this.getView().setModel(oModel);
```

Unfortunately the popover is still empty :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to set your model on the popover, which you are not currently doing like so:

```
this._oPopover.setModel(oModel); //note you must do this after the model is accessible
```

Alternatively, and in my opinion a better way, is to add the popover as a view dependent like so:

```
...

if (!this._oPopover){
  this._oPopover = new sap.m.Popover("popover",{
    id:"pop",
    placement:sap.m.PlacementType.Bottom,
    showHeader:false,
    contentWidth:"320px",
    contentHight:"500px"
  });
}

//Add the popover as a view dependent, giving it access to the view model
this.getView().addDependent(this._oPopover);

...
```

Let me know how you get on!